# How to show multiple options in configurable products in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

I want to create one configurable product shirt in Magento. I have added one attributes color and size.There are three sizes small, medium and Large and 2 colors red and blue. 
Now a customer want to buy 3 red shirts of small, medium and large size each. That means the structure will be like:

```
Product Name: Shirt

Size :  Small  (Multi Select)
        Medium
        Large  

Color : Red  (Dropdown)
        Blue
```

Here customer can select multiple size but only one color at a time. 
Also the price of the product will be differ as per size and color.
I tried in attributes but when I create attribute and select 'Catalog Input Type for Store Owner' Multi select, the option 'Use To Create Configurable Product' gets hidden. Is it possible to create such product?

Comment: How come that size is multi-select? how does this work for the customers?

Comment: Actually I have given just an example here. I am having 3-4 attributes over there.

Comment: You can't do that in Magento, that would take quite a lot of work to do something like that as well due to the way the configurable products work.
That would not work in a generic way, what if you had more than one multiple box it would be impossible to work that way